# DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel when attempting to send invite upon guild creation

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm using v12. I'm trying to get my bot to send me an invite after it creates a guild with this code:

```
client.on('message', message => {  
    if(message.content.startsWith('!guild')) {  
    client.guilds.create('Bot Server', 'london')  
    .then(guild => {guild.channels.cache.first().createInvite()  
    .then(invite => client.users.cache.get('<myID>').send(invite.url))  
    .catch(error => console.log(error))  
    })  
    }})
```

It succeeds at creating a server, but fails at sending me an invite:

```
DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel
at RequestHandler.execute (c:\Users\User\Desktop\Bot Server\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {name: 'DiscordAPIError',
message: 'Unknown Channel', method: 'post', path: '/channels/740129814459187242/invites', code: 10003}
```

I simply want to see that a bot can own a server on discord, but cannot get the invite message from the bot. At this point, I'm stumped. It has been shown that it is possible in the documentation from [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=create) and [discord.com](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#create-guild). How do I go about sending an invite to myself, or send the invite to the channel I used the command to create a guild?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a `Guild` is created, whether it was created by a bot or not, it will have 2 categories, "Text Channels" and "Voice Channels", one containing a `TextChannel` and the other one a `VoiceChannel`.

Categories are counted as channels. `Guild.channels.cache.first()` will always be a `Category`, and you cannot create invites on categories.

To fix this issue, you'll have to filter all the channels in the `Guild` and choose the first `Channel` in the `Collection`.

---

```js
client.guilds.create("MyGuild").then(guild => {
    // Filtering all the channels.
    const channels = guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == "text");
    // --> channels is a collection.

    channels.first().createInvite().then(invite => {
        message.channel.send(`Here is your invite: ${invite.url}`);
    })
})
```